# Get binding id of field in override method in android. Dynamic binding?

Tags: java, android, overriding

Is it possible to retrieve the id of the field for which it is called in onItemClick? I have many fields and would like to dynamically bind fields and change their values.
By the id, i mean, the ID name of binding layout file, in that case its: "idCorrectionData".

```
LinkedList<Double> rangeListCorrection = new LinkedList<>();
                for (double j = 0; j <= 600; j += 1) {
                    rangeListCorrection.add(j);
                }
ArrayAdapter<Double> arrayAdapterCorrection = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_item, rangeListCorrection);
binding.idCorrectionData.setAdapter(arrayAdapterCorrection);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// ?? ?? binding.MY_FIELD_ID.setText(“text was changed”)
//what is id of field that called onitemClick method?
}
```

I would like to point out that on click is initially called for an arrayAdapter that is assigned to a field, and that field's ID I would like to get. In this case: I'm looking for the (id) field: **idCorrectionData** in the override method.

Is it possible to retrieve the parent or view id of the field for which the values are changed?
Should I do it in a different method, or should I do it with my own?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to achieve there as in the adapter you should know the view you are using, but if that is unknown you should at least know the id of the field you want to use. You can rely on dynamic variables after that and use something like this: `binding.setVariable(BR.item, item);`.

> The Data Binding Library generates a class named BR in the module package which contains the IDs of the resources used for data binding

Comment: my problem is that I have many fields, each with a different adapter, I don't know which field will be changed at the moment? I thought to get to the id field, because after I change the value in the layout I have to refer to another method so that it starts the thread of connecting to the driver in order to change the value, and all the time I need the ID of the field being changed to know , what field in the driver should I change.
So my only problem is how to find out which field with which ID has just been changed.

Comment: Using `view.getId()` is not working for you in that case?

Comment: hmm, it is possible that I misspelled, when I said id I meant the name of the field that has been bound, i.e. I am looking for the name of the field to which the adapter that called the onClick method belongs

Comment: You can do the check `view.getId == R.id.idCorrectionData` to only do something only for that one.

Comment: With the information & code you shared it is hard to figure out what you want to achieve, but I would recommend to revisit your approach as something doesn't feel right in your approach.

Comment: unfortunately the id's are different, probably because i'm in the adapter, and i don't know how to take something like view.getParentId or something like that, because i assume the id i need, maybe there is a "level" higher or something?

Comment: You can go up in the hierarchy and find the id you want: `int parentId = ((View) view.getParent()).getId();`.